# HTML5 tags remove by Rich Text Box in UmbracoCMS

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, richtextbox, umbraco7

How to fix, HTML5 tags automatically remove by Rich Text Box in UmbracoCMS.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Dhamat, can you be a bit more specific? Which HTML5 tags are removed from the RTE? Which version of Umbraco are you running?

Comment: Hello Thomas, Remove tags such as **section** and **article** using umbraco version umbraco7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into the TinyMce configuration. The richtext editor in Umbraco is using this component and it is configured to remove certain elements by default.

To allow for specific elements or attributes to be used in the editor, you would need to change the default configuration.

It is documented here in the `validElements` part:
https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/config/tinymceconfig/#validelements